# Custom Audio Playback Library and System-wide Audio Player

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, xcode

I have written a custom playback library in C for audio files (ie. MP3, OGG).  It has some proprietary technology I want to apply packet by packet to the audio.

I want to play back music files using this C library, but I want to use the iOS audio player to play audio in the background.  I have set up the `info.plist` file to have the `Required Background Mode` of `App plays audio`, but I'm not sure how to get my C playback library to take advantage of this feature.

HALP!